# Google Fit - how to prepare the app for sensitive scope

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-fit

Does anyone know how to get permission to sensitive scope before OAuth verification process? I want to use ".../auth/fitness.blood_pressure.write", which is sensitive, however when requesting permission to that on Android I get info that Google disabled the app(because OAuth verification process is not completed). So if This scope cannot be granted upon verification, then how can I test the feature?

Scopes requested within the app:

```
val options: FitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
    .addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
    .addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_PRESSURE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
        .build()
fun account(context: Context) = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(context, options)

fun enable(fragment: Fragment) {
    if (!hasPermission(fragment.requireContext())) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                fragment,
                GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                account(fragment.requireContext()),
                options)
    } else {
        initListener?.onCompleted()
    }
}

fun hasPermission(context: Context) =
        GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account(context), options)
```

Scopes added in console:
[image]

Error in the app when calling requestPermissions
[image]

Comment: Is the app set to production?  please edit your question include your code.  and the full error message.

Comment: No, because I want to develop the feature before sending to production. For other scopes that's possible, however seems to not for sensitive scopes

Comment: Did you add the scopes in the Oauth screen?  There is a section where you can supply scopes

Comment: Yes, I did add the scopes. They are just not verified

Comment: Would you mind putting a screen shot in of the scopes you added to your Oauth2 screen. And the full error message.   I will ping someone at Google for you but they will need to see the information i have requested if you want help.

Comment: Updated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Email sent, I will let you know when i hear back.  If you are lucky someone may respond here directly.

Comment: Thanks. Google OAuth verification process feels like be driven by bot, because the discussion with them totally doesn't make sense.

Comment: There have been some "issues" with the verification process (IMO).  However there is a good reason we have it and Google has been great about addressing the issues.

Comment: Any news? The only idea I have is to break functionality on production and release untested code.

Comment: The only think they said was that you need to start the verification process which seams strange to me.